# how to add values to hashmap only after editing completed from editext using textwatcher in android

Tags: java, android, textwatcher

I have multiple LinearLayouts having edittexts which implements textwatcher,So when i enters any value it directly put to hashmap,but i want to add a complete value after finished editing,My code is as below:

```
TextWatcher textwatcher = new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            calculateInvoice();
            HashMap<String, String> descMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            descMap.put("qty", et_qty.getText().toString() + "");
            descMap.put("upriz", et_unit_prize.getText().toString() + "");
            descMap.put("amt", subtotal + "");

            System.out.println("::::::::::::::::::MAP VALUES::::::::::" + descMap);

            descList.add(descMap);

        }
    };
```

Comment: You need to associate a position/index in your data structure with each edit text. Then you can append/modify the corresponding item in your data structure.

Comment: @Eu.Dr.-can u pls send me sample code like this?

Comment: Please see the answer I have posted, hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Let you have 5 editText Views that are defined in xml file. Say they are editText0,editText1...editText4.

Now in your Activity class,

## 1

construct a String Array: String[] Data = new String[5]

## 2

Add Text watcher to each EditTexts, individually. like :

```
editText0.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {}

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,int arg3) {}

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable Token) 
            {
                final int index = 0; // as this Text Watcher is specifically for editText0
                Data[index] = Token.toString();

            }
        });
```

## 3

Similarly add a TextWatcher to all 4 remaining EditTextViews.